# Firebase messaging - testing with Curl once Vapid implemented

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm struggling with the firebase instructions to test my setup part way using Curl- see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message. I suspect these have fallen out of date now that Vapid is being used.

I've tried with the values at A, B & C in the picture for the Bearer part, and use the token that `getToken` returned, but every time I run:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer BGp....................3pPSJmA" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ \
    "message":{ \
        "notification": { \
        "title": "FCM Message", \
        "body": "This is an FCM Message", \
        }, \
        "token": "dx1.............3sAnnCA" \
        } \ 
    }' https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project-name>/messages:send
```

I get

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

My code is not working in general so I'm very keen to try to test mid-way steps using such Curl commands. **Should I be using A, B or C, and what do I need to do to the Curl command to get it to work?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using A, the server key, as the bearer token in your authorization header. The token returned by `getToken` is the registration token for a device that's subscribed to push notifications from your app.

Edit: My answer applies to the traditional FCM API - those docs do appear to be out of date in that they don't discuss VAPID support. With VAPID you should be using a signed JWT token for the auth header. See here ("Introducing VAPID for server identification") for more info: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/web-push-interop-wins